# How do I get the time difference between two DateTime objects using C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I get the time difference between two `DateTime` objects using C#?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to do this:

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2010, 05, 12, 13, 15, 00);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2010, 05, 12, 13, 45, 00);
Console.WriteLine(b.Subtract(a).TotalMinutes);
```

When executed this prints "30" since there is a 30 minute difference between the date/times.

The result of `DateTime.Subtract(DateTime x)` is a [TimeSpan Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) which gives other useful properties.

Comment: To display the difference, do something like this:`Console.WriteLine((a - b).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"))`.  See: [MSDN Custom TimeSpan Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This worked for me. I just wanted to how many seconds it takes for client to make a REST call and get reply back.

Comment: Pay attention to use `TotalMinutes`! (not `Minutes`)

Comment: Subtract don't exist in visual studio 2019

Comment: Why in the world are the `ToString` format specifiers different than all other format strings in .NET?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: Maybe a bit off topic here, but if you want to have some counter in time in your code, use Stopwatch instead calculating the time difference between two DateTime.

Answer (score 81):

You want the [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0) struct:

```
TimeSpan diff = dateTime1 - dateTime2;
```

> A `TimeSpan` object represents a time interval (duration of time or elapsed time) that is measured as a positive or negative number of days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of a second. The `TimeSpan` structure can also be used to represent the time of day, but only if the time is unrelated to a particular date.

There are various methods for getting the days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds back from this structure.

If you are just interested in the difference then:

```
TimeSpan diff = (dateTime1 - dateTime2).Duration();
```

will give you the positive difference between the times regardless of the order.

If you have just got the time component but the times could be split by midnight then you need to add 24 hours to the span to get the actual difference:

```
TimeSpan diff = dateTime1 - dateTime2;
if (diff < 0)
{
    diff = diff + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 35):

What you need is to use the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(VS.90).aspx) classs Subtract method, which returns a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(VS.90).aspx).

```
var dateOne = DateTime.Now;
var dateTwo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
var diff = dateTwo.Subtract(dateOne);
var res = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", diff.Hours,diff.Minutes,diff.Seconds));
```

Answer (score 13):

The way I usually do it is subtracting the two DateTime and this gets me a TimeSpan that will tell me the diff.

Here's an example:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
// Do some work
TimeSpan timeDiff = DateTime.Now - start;
timeDiff.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 5):

IF they are both UTC date-time values you can do `TimeSpan diff = dateTime1 - dateTime2;`

Otherwise your chance of getting the correct answer in every single possible case is zero.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var startDate = new DateTime(2007, 3, 24);

 var endDate = new DateTime(2009, 6, 26);

 var dateDiff = endDate.Subtract(startDate);

 var date = string.Format("{0} years {1} months {2} days", (int)dateDiff.TotalDays / 365, 
 (int)(dateDiff.TotalDays % 365) / 30, (int)(dateDiff.TotalDays % 365) / 30);

 Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).   Here is some sample code:

```
TimeSpan sincelast = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - LastUpdate.Ticks);
```

Comment: Or just `TimeSpan sincelast = DateTime.Now - LastUpdate;`

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan timespan;
    timespan = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
    int timeDifference = timespan.Days;
    MessageBox.Show(timeDifference.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use in following manner to achieve difference between two Datetime Object. Suppose there are DateTime objects dt1 and dt2 then the code.

```
TimeSpan diff = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
```