# Getting time difference between two values

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In my application I have 4 TextBoxes, and 2 TextBoxes to enter the start-time, and 2 TextBoxes to enter end-time.

The user will always enter a completed time, so the input will always be 11:30, 12:45, and so on.

How can I get the difference in hours and minutes between start and endtime?

Comment: Something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821040/how-do-i-get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-using-c).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use TimeSpan class, and Subtract method of DateTime.

```
        DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
        DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);
        TimeSpan ts = t1.Subtract(t2);
```

Comment: This works great, but the result is 02:30:00, is it possible to remove the seconds so it will display something like this 2:30?

Comment: If you're only working with time, you really should be using `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: `TimeSpan` class has some more useful properties as well e.g. `TotalSeconds`, `TotalMinutes` etc. which can be used here after `TimeSpan` object `ts` has been obtained.

Answer (score 6):

You can get a `TimeSpan` of the difference by subtractraction.

```
TimeSpan time1 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox1.Text);
TimeSpan time2 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox2.Text);

TimeSpan difference = time1 - time2;

int hours = difference.Hours;
int minutes = difference.Minutes;
```

Answer (score 5):

create two `DateTime` objects parsing the values in the `TextBox` controls and simply subtract the two `DateTime`, you will get a `TimeSpan` object which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

use TimeSpan, no need to use dates

```
var start = TimeSpan.Parse(start.Text);
var end = TimeSpan.Parse(end.Text);

TimeSpan result = end - start;
var diffInMinutes = result.TotalMinutes();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use timespan :

```
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(starttime.text);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(endtime.text);

    TimeSpan result = dt2 - dt1;
```

Then you can get the minutes, seconds etc from result.

Answer (score 0):

convert the hours to minutes, add it to the existing minutes, convert those down to total seconds, do the same with endtime. minus them from each other, convert them back up to hours and minutes. remembering 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute, thats how i would deal with it. because total seconds will always be the same, its hard trying to teach a computer trying to wrap around from 60 back to 0 or from 12 to 1. much easier to use somethign perfectly linear like seconds. then reconvert upwards

Comment: as you can see im more for doing the logic myself so its more understandable to me, rather than everyone else just making date times... xD

Comment: This is imho overly complicated, TimeSpan is way easier and safer to user.

Comment: im used to being given challenges from my old tutor where we would have to do thigns without using built in functions to better understand how it worked and to teach us to be more logical, still havent broken that habit sadly

Comment: You should try to break that habit. While it is useful to understand how things work, it is also important to save time and money by using built-in functions that are known to work. Reinventing the wheel every time is not only expensive, but also error prone. C# has very powerful classes, learn to make use of them. :)

Comment: oh i know i mean we did it for these simple ones so when we got to more complex algorithms that didnt have built in functions we werent sat there like lemons thinking well i dont know why dont they make a thing for it? this way atleast teaches from the start to be independent and self reliant, though ofc i make sure to use a reliable pre built function when possibble. im just used to haveing to do them myself XD

Comment: But this requirement is not actually that simple.  One big reason to use the framework types (`DateTime` and `TimeSpan`) is that the parsing functions for these types have well documented localizable behavior.  If you write the function yourself, you will run into trouble if a user uses some format other than the format or formats you've coded for (`2:45 PM` or `2.45 PM` or `14:45` or `14.45` or some other option you're not aware of).

Comment: I didn't want to say anything against learning stuff that way. When I'm interested in something I like to try it myself too. Your answer is a nice alternative, but I'd recommend to use a TimeSpan and point to the alternative if it is done for learning purposes. :)

Comment: very true, i agree with you both :) just used to writing my own for more complex functions, havent had to deal with easy ones where things already exist for a while and to be honest i forgot about this one XD

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Parse(txtbox1.Text) - Datetime.Parse(txtbox2.Text);
```

Example:

```
TimeSpan difference =  DateTime.Parse("12:55")-DateTime.Parse("11:45");
double hourDiff=  difference.TotalHours;
double minutes = difference.TotalMinutes;
Console.WriteLine(hourDiff);//1.16666666666667
Console.WriteLine(minutes);//70
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract two `DateTime`s and receive a `TimeSpan` structure. This has properties for retrieving `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds`, etc.

```
var first = new DateTime(2012, 05, 08, 10, 30, 00);
var second = new DateTime(2012, 05, 08, 11, 49, 13);

var diff = first - second;
var hours = diff.Hours;
var mins = diff.Minutes;
```