# Calculation of time diff due to percent change in travel time

Tags: c#, time

I'm fairly new to programming and have just came across this site and am hoping i can get a little help with something im working on.

My objective is to determine a new delivery time with a 25% delay added onto the original delivery time. This is to be done in a windows forms application. The user is to enter the original delivery start and end times in their respective text boxes and when clicking a button the new delivery time will be displayed in its respective text box. This is what i have so far.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const double PERCENT = 0.25;


        DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_StartT.Text);
        DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_EndT.Text);
        TimeSpan ts = t1.Subtract(t2);
        double tsMin = (double)Convert.ToDouble(ts);
        double tsMinTot = ts.TotalMinutes;
        short tsMinPercent = (short)(((double)tsMinTot) * PERCENT);
        double tsAndPercentTot = tsMinPercent + tsMinTot;
        DateTime newTimeMinTot = Convert.ToDateTime(tsAndPercentTot);

        int hours = newTimeMinTot.Hour;
        int minutes = newTimeMinTot.Minute;

        string newTimeStrg = string.Format("{0:d1}:{1:d2}", hours, minutes);


        txtB_NewDelivT.Text = newTimeStrg;
```

So i have attempted towork around the issue but still throwing errors

Comment: is there a reason you dont use DateTime and TimeSpan classes?
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime
and im sorry your code is too hard to read.
simple debugging should help you.

Comment: Was just about to suggest the same thing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500095/getting-time-difference-between-two-values

Comment: Yes, and that's because i have no idea how to use DateTime. As i said im new to programming with no prior experience. How will a debugging help?

Comment: that link deff helps with the first part of the problem. How would i go about finding 25% of my time difference?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do what you need:

```
    //Initial Delivery 5 Days
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now; //User Enters todayy as start
    DateTime end = start.AddDays(5); //User enters 5 days from now as end.

    //Get the ticks between now and 5 days time
    long ticksDiff = end.Ticks - start.Ticks;

    //Calculate 25% of difference
    long percentOfTicks = (long)(((double)ticksDiff) * 0.25);

    //This is your new date (orifiginal delivery date + 25%)
    DateTime newDelayedStart = end.AddTicks(percentOfTicks);
```

Comment: This is great, more along the lines of what i was trying to do. How would i change that to only be in hh:mm format. This should take place within a 24 hour period.

Comment: Its teh same, just define teh date and time on the date time:

Comment: Like this             DateTime start = new DateTime(2015, 2, 10, 6, 0, 0);
            DateTime end = new DateTime(2015, 2, 10, 15, 0, 0);

Comment: Ive attempted to fix the problem. Now its throwing an exception error.  DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtB_StartT.Text);                            String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @Soto, that's a different issue, not related to this question. There are many many other threads here on stackoverflow related to that issue. Try searching for "parsing strings to datetime" and the like.