# Difference between two times C#

Tags: c#, time

I have this code. I would like to get the difference of two times. If you look through the code the output between 23 and 7 gives -16 and i would like the output to be 8 hours since that's the difference between those two. I tried converting them in 12h format still not working. Running out of ideas.

```
DateTime TFrom;
DateTime TTo;
string TimeFrom = "23:00:00";
string TimeTo = "07:00:00";
if (DateTime.TryParse(TimeFrom, out TFrom) && DateTime.TryParse(TimeTo, out TTo))
{
     TimeSpan TS = TTo - TFrom;
     int hour = TS.Hours;
     int mins = TS.Minutes;
     int secs = TS.Seconds;
     string timeDiff = hour.ToString("00") + ":" + mins.ToString("00") + ":" + secs.ToString("00");
     Label1.Text = timeDiff.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Already answered 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821040/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I don't believe this is a duplicate, given that OP *is* using a `TimeSpan` for the difference, but the input "dates" are not really dates, which is why any of the suggested solutions in the linked question will not work, and this question is different. Voting to reopen

Comment: Your problem appears to be that your inputs are not really dates, but "time of days" without a day component. Given that you know that that the "to" date must be equal to or larger than the "from" date, you can work around that by using a little trick, adding 24 hours if the "to" date is smaller: `TimeSpan TS = dTo > dFrom ? dTo - dFrom : dTo.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(24)) - dFrom;`

Comment: My mistake for not changing the variables names, but thanks for saying that's a different question, I kind of tried everything that i found around here about subtracting two times, all of them are working but when I gave them that input I don't get the correct number of hours

Comment: I used exactly what you said and it is working perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: @AlexandruCosmin you are welcome. If this question is reopened, I could try to add it as an answer. A tip for any next question: be very clear in your question **and** its title. Use appropriate formatting to highlight important parts of your question, like the input examples and expected vs. actual outputs (see [here on how to do that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). Also, you can still improve this question by giving it an [edit].