# Difference Between Two Times in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time

I have read several discussions about this topic like following one.

[How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821040/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects)

But I could not find answer for my question.

```
public DateTime retunPureTime(int min,int sec)
{
    DateTime mydate= new DateTime(2000, 12, 23, 14, 40, 20);

    retrun ????????;
}
```

I need to return a `DateTime` object reduce by parameter values. for a example if **pass min=3 and sec=30,**

I need to return following date.

```
DateTime(2000, 12, 23, 14, 36, 50);
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @MelanciaUK While a `TimeSpan` object sounds like what is desired from the question title, the description sounds like he literally just wants to reduce a given `DateTime` object by N minutes and Y seconds rather than -- to use his own words -- the difference between two times.

Comment: Do you need a time difference or a new date time ? There is an ambiguity in your question and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can add time by using the Add methods (AddSeconds,AddMinutes, etc.). You can also subtract time by using the Subtract method. It takes a DateTime parameter.

So, if you want to subtract 3 minutes and 30 seconds you could do:

```
DateTime myDate= new DateTime(2000, 12, 23, 14, 40, 20);
var foo = new DateTime();
var subtraction = foo.AddMinutes(3).AddSeconds(30);

return myDate.Subtract(subtraction);
```

Comment: `DateTime` is immutable, `AddMinutes` will return a new `DateTime` instance, not alter the instance you call the method on.

Comment: @TrevorPilley: OP didnot ask for the same object to be returned.This is more elegant.

Comment: @NirajDoshi Yiu didn't get the Trevor's point. This will do nothing.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: Sorry my bad. I get it now !

Comment: @TrevorPilley Doh. You're right. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
return mydate - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(min * 60 + sec);
```