# how to find the hours between 2 dateTime in azure table storage using c#

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

**I want find the number of hours in azure table storage**

```
public UserTimeSheet GetTotalHoursByYear()
    {
        CloudTable cloudTable = GetCloudTable();
        var query = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
        {
            SelectColumns = new List<string>()
        {
            "SignInTime", "SignOutTime"
        }
        };
        var queryOutput = cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented<DynamicTableEntity>(query, null);

        var results = queryOutput.Results.ToList();
        foreach (var entity in results)
        {

        }
        return null;// results.ToList();
    }
```

**I have return the code which select 2 dateTime columns. But i am not getting how get differnce of hours and sum it up. Please me to solve this.**

Comment: You can calculate the difference between two DateTime variables using the explanation showed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821040/how-do-i-get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-using-c. I suppose that work with the columns is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the code below(and please feel free to modify the code to meet your need):

```
        //other code.

        var queryOutput = cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented<DynamicTableEntity>(query, null);

        var results = queryOutput.Results.ToList();
        foreach (var entity in results)
        {
            var start = DateTime.Parse(entity.Properties["SignInTime"].StringValue);
            var end = DateTime.Parse(entity.Properties["SignOutTime"].StringValue);                

            var diff_hour = end.Subtract(start).Hours;
            Console.WriteLine("the hours between signIn and signOut is: " + diff_hour);
        }
```

Here is the test result at my side:

[image]

**Note:**

In my table, the type of **SignInTime** and **SignOutTime** is **String**, not **DateTime**. And if you set the 2 columns' type as **DateTime**, you just need a little change to my code.

[image]